# npm: when i use npm link a dependency package, dependency package has path alias

Tags: npm, webpack, babeljs

when i use npm link a dependency package.
dependency package has a webpack config path alias

```
    extensions: [".tsx", ".js", ".ts"],
    alias: { "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "src") },
}
```

throw a error:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/sub' in '/Users/zhangyuqing/Documents/lib-demo/src'

Comment: bro please help me

Comment: Brothers in the world, please help me

Comment: giving more details around the settings that's related to this piece of error, helps in understanding the context